# If the Namekians can "create" an extremely powerful dragon, why couldn't they help stop Buu?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

The Namekians created the dragonballs and their associated dragons. These dragons are imbued with extreme power, so much so that the Supreme Kais were astounded when they first saw them (Buu saga). The dragons have the power to do things that the rulers of the universe cannot.

If the dragons have such awesome power, it follows that the Namekians do aswell (if not, where does the power come from). If so, why aren't the Namekians involved in helping the Z warriors fight Buu when he is destroying the universe?

Comment: King Piccolo easily destroyed Earth's dragon in Dragon Ball.  Not Piccolo, King Piccolo.  The dragons aren't powerful, not even close.  They do, however, have abilities that all mortals lack and apparently all immortals lack.  Also remember, the Supreme Kai was not the creator of the universe, he was a 'guardian' of a sector of the universe.  There were three other Supreme Kais before Buu, and they all answered to another higher power.  Again, the dragons aren't powerful, they just have different abilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The short answer : because Buu was more powerful than the dragon.**

Statement : *The dragons have the power to do things that the rulers of the universe cannot*. Where does this information come from ? As you stated, the power of the dragon depends of the power of its maker. The first dragon we meet can only resurrect one person per wish, whereas the latest can resurrect the entire Earth population. This is because the Namekians perfected their art of dragon creation. And probably because they grow more powerful with time.

Buu is an extremely powerful being whose powers match the Supreme Kais'. He can instantaneously tranform people into candies. He can even transform Vegeto, an also extremely powerful being, into chocolate. He can regenerate at a rate which make fighting against him nearly impossible. Remember that Buu *ate* one of the Kai...

The guy is tough, that's it.

EDIT : You did not define "Ruler of the Universe" in your question. To me, *Supreme Kai* and *Ruler of the Universe* aren't the same thing. The Kais are more like a police. If there was really a "Ruler of the Universe" in Dragon Ball, I think it would be the guy who ruled heaven.

Regarding your second comment, we can only guess than resurrecting the most powerful saiyans requires as much power as resurrecting the most average human, not more. In the series, resurrecting merely means "bringing back the soul from heaven".

Comment: Not just one of the Kais, [the most supreme of kais.](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Supreme_Kai)

Comment: In regards to your first sentence, the dragon can bring someone back to life, while the kais cannot (they can trade lives though). I don't think the Namekian's "perfect their art" of creating dragons, but I do know that the Namekian dragon is stronger because it was the first.

Comment: I guess I should have been clearer in my question. If the dragon has enough power to resurrect enough people who have the power to kill Buu, wouldn't that mean the dragon has enough power to just kill Buu directly?

Comment: @MaxMackie I edited to reflect what I think in regards to your comments. Feel free to give me your feedback

Comment: Yeah I think your edits make more sense, thanks :)

Comment: Also keep in mind this is Japanese Mythology.  Supreme rulers of the afterlife are not necessarily all-powerful.  In fact, God is basically Kami, and 'the guy in charge of heaven' would actually be King Yemma, who is less powerful than Goku by the time he fights Buu.  In fact, **All** the Kais are less powerful than Goku by the time he fights Buu, meaning they definitely, most certainly, are less powerful than Buu (since Goku alone can't beat him).

Comment: @n0pe Nowhere is it stated that bringing back someone powerful is any more difficult than bringing back someone weak.  If the dragon is simply repairing a physical body, then opening a link for the appropriate soul to return through, then it doesn't matter how much power/ki the soul is dragging around - the dragon isn't doing the heavy-lifting by that point.

Answer (score 1):

The dragon's power is limited to the power of its creator, this is seen where they make a wish to kill the saiyans and the wish cannot be granted as the saiyans are much stronger than kami, there was even reference to the fact that the namekians boosted the wishing power of the dragon while they were on new namek. Although, I do wonder why they don't just wish "transport the enemy into the center of the sun". Also I remember the namekians saying that they don't believe in wishing away all of their problems. Like how they didn't just wish away the great drought that almost destroyed planet namek.